# C - pointer problems and void method problems

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, void

I have problems with the following code in C. Basically I want to create two threads and give them both the integer value of "ergebnis" . After this the threads should have to calculate on this value seperately and print their individual result.

while compiling I get this errors:

```
3.2.c: In function ‘erhoehenumeins’:
3.2.c:10:13: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer [enabled by default]
3.2.c:10:13: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
3.2.c: In function ‘verdoppeln’:
3.2.c:20:18: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘void *’ and ‘int’)
```

**the code:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *erhoehenumeins(void * dummy) {
    printf("Thread erhoehenumeins() wurde gestartet\n");
    int temp;
    temp= dummy+1;
    printf("Thread erhoehenumeins() wurde beendet\n");
    printf("Ergebnis=%d\n",temp);
}
void *verdoppeln(void * dummy) {
    printf("Thread verdoppeln() wurde gestartet\n");
    int temp=dummy*2;
    printf("Thread verdoppeln() wurde beendet\n");
    printf("Ergebnis=%d\n",temp);
}

int main() {
    int ergebnis=3;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    // Thread 1 erzeugen
    pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, &erhoehenumeins, &ergebnis );

    // Thread 2 erzeugen
    pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, &verdoppeln, &ergebnis );

    // Main-Thread wartet auf beide Threads.
    pthread_join( thread1, NULL );
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL );
    printf("\nHaupt-Thread main() wurde beendet\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well, you don't return anything from your functions for starters...

Comment: Just a side-note: Your indentation (or rather the lack of it) makes this harder to read than it needs to be. Regarding your question: http://pastebin.com/1XNrKfBc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
int temp=dummy*2;
```

the value `dummy` is a `void *` -- the compiler can't multiply this by 2.

Perhaps you should do this"

```
int temp = (*(int *)dummy)*2;
```

Comment: thanks very much for your quick answer. Wehen i follow your explanations i get the error: 3.2.c: In function ‘verdoppeln’:
3.2.c:20:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: I can't see why; perhaps you should edit your question with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
void * erhoehenumeins(void * dummy)
{
    int * p = (int *) dummy;
    ++*p;

    return NULL;
}
```

And:

```
int ergebnis = 3;
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &erhoehenumeins, &ergebnis);
```

This is of course undefined behaviour and completely broken, but it should do for now.